# Athena: how to get a value based on filtered index in array of structs

Tags: arrays, filter, amazon-athena

I have a S3 table(test) with a column(sample) in array of struct format.

```
[{index=1, value='A'}, {index=2, value='B'}, {index=3, value='F'}, ...]
```

I tried this query and it works:

```
SELECT 
date, 
MAX(case when s.index = 1 then s.value else NULL end) AS a1,
MAX(case when s.index = 3 then s.value else NULL end) as a2
FROM test,
UNNEST(sample) AS t(s)
group by date;
```

Is there any way I can do the same without using unnest (e.g using filter function)?

Comment: You should be able to combine `filter` (https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html#filter), `transform` (https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html#transform) and `array_max` (https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html#array_max). (As Athena is based on Presto 0.172, I'm giving pointers to docs for this version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html) to process the arrays:

```
SELECT
  date,
  MAX(array_max(transform(filter(sample, e -> e.index = 1), e -> e.value))) AS a1,
  MAX(array_max(transform(filter(sample, e -> e.index = 3), e -> e.value))) AS a2,
FROM test
GROUP BY 1
```

`filter` selects the elements with the index you are after, `transform` extracts the `value` properties from the selected elements, and `array_max` returns the max value.

Comment: when I run it, gives this error: 
"array_max"("transform"("filter"("sample", ("e") -> ("e"."index" = 1)), ("e") -> "e"."value"))' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you need to wrap it in `MAX` too to get the max value over all rows, not just the max value per row. I have updated my example.

Comment: yes correct, it works perfectly. Actually if group by removed we dont need to wrap it in MAX... thank you very much

Comment: The grouping is there so you'll get the max value per date, without it you'll end up with multiple rows for the same date.